# servant throwError with custom monad stack

Tags: haskell, servant

given a monad like this:

```
newtype App a = App
  { runApp :: ReaderT AppEnv (LoggingT IO) a
  }
  deriving newtype
    ( Functor,
      Applicative,
      Monad,
      MonadIO, 
      MonadReader AppEnv,
      MonadLogger
    )

newtype AppEnv = AppEnv -- environment for the app
```

I'd like to use the standard error handling from Servant using `throwError`:

```
foo :: App ()
foo = throwError err404
```

which doesn't compile

```
    • No instance for (Control.Monad.Error.Class.MonadError
                         ServerError App)
        arising from a use of ‘throwError’
    • In the expression: throwError err404
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo = throwError err404
```

and I can't find a way to make that work. Can I derive such an instance for `App`? Do I need to change the monad stack?

I could use `throw`, but that does change the behavior of `servant-client`, which I want to avoid.

Comment: normaly those kind of errors means that you have to make an instance of `MonadError ServerError` for your stack. I don't know more about servant though

Comment: [this](https://docs.servant.dev/en/stable/cookbook/using-custom-monad/UsingCustomMonad.html) might interest you.

Comment: @Ismor I think that's exactly what I want, thank you! I missed that in the first place. However, it seems that switching from plain IO to a custom monad stack changes the behavior of servant-client, which is the actual issue I'm observing

Comment: You can also eliminate the indirection and derive via the reader transformer `newtype App a = App
  { runApp :: AppEnv -> LoggingT IO a } deriving (Functor, .., MonadError ServerError) via ReaderT AppEnv (LoggingT IO)`.

Comment: @l7r7 Changing the monad in the server shouldn't change the behaviour of the client. Clients are derived from the abstract API definition, which doesn't mention any monad.

Comment: @danidaz You're entirely right, I messed that up on my side. I had one `throwError` and one `throw` in my code, which led to different behavior. the client works fine

Comment: @Iceland_jack that's nice! thanks for suggesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to `throwError` values of type `ServerError`, our monad needs to be an instance of `MonadError ServerError`. Looking at the [available instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html), we can get an idea of what we would need to add to our monad stack.

These instances won't work because they are for specific error types different from `ServerError`:

```
MonadError IOException IO
MonadError () Maybe
```

This instance would force us to use `Either` as our base monad:

```
MonadError e (Either e)
```

Then there are a whole bunch of "passthrough" instances that propagate the `MonadError` constraint from the base monad, but don't introduce it:

```
MonadError e m => MonadError e (IdentityT m)
MonadError e m => MonadError e (ReaderT r m)
MonadError e m => MonadError e (StateT s m)
...
```

This is the instance we need:

```
Monad m => MonadError e (ExceptT e m)
```

We need to add an `ExceptT ServerError` transformer somewhere in our monad stack, and newtype derive `MonadError ServerError`.

An annoyance with this solution is that introducing `ExceptT` might make operations like [`catch`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:catch) (for runtime exceptions) more difficult to perform.

Comment: The `MonadCatch` typeclass https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.7/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadCatch from the "exceptions" package might help with catching runtime exceptions in monad stacks with `ExceptT`.